# Defaulting result in case expression using count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently am casing off of a big select statement. I am trying to work through the case portion. I currently have the case set up where it will take the name 'Brad' where units are 'inches'.

If I get rid of the units, it will show more than one result. Is there a way to default in the case statement where the case returns more than one result for 'brad'? Where if there is only 1 result, it will show that result, otherwise if there is more than 1 result, use units = 'inches'?

Here is the working case statement:

```
And case when R.name = 'Brad' and R.units ='Inches' then 0 else 1 End = 1
```

Here is a non working semi-psedu version of what I'd like to do:

```
And case when Count(R.name ='Brad') > 1 then (R.name = 'Brad' and R.units = 'Inches') else (R.name = 'Brad' ) End
```

Regardless it should return 1 result, default to inches if it returns more than 1 for the name 'Brad'

Here is the portion of the statement how it is joined.

```
select r.name, r.units, r.blah
From items I
Inner Join Results.R (NoLock)
ON I.Code = R.Code
WHERE  r.status IN ('Y','N')
And case when R.name = 'Brad' and R.units ='Inches' then 0 else 1 End = 1
```

Comment: Show us some more of the select, not just the case expression. And tag the dbms used.

Comment: @jarlh It is just a bunch of joins between tables. It won't provide any help. The only two columns I'm working with are R.name and R.unites. The working case statement will return one row where the units is inches. If i take out the units, it will show all of the rows returned for name brad. Is there a way to default r.units = 'inches' if the case creates more than 1 r.name ='Brad'?

Comment: It makes difference if it's a part of the select list, or found in ON or WHERE.

Comment: BTW, case expression, not statement.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?  What is the result that you want?

Comment: In my working sql case, it is fixed to work with units='inches'. Therefore I get one row. If I remove units='inches' I get 3 rows.(Rows always change upon different names). If I get more than 1 row, I want it to use unit's='inches' which will return 1 row, otherwise if it's just 1 row, use the provided units whether that is feet, meters, etc.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` in the `WHERE` clause instead of `case` expressions. Your case is converted to `... and (R.name <> 'Brad' or R.units <> 'Inches')`.